# Alma 9.1 Samba config not allowing outside connections

Tags: redhat, samba

I just installed Alma 9.1 on my homelab, and I've attempted to install samba everything seems to work okay locally. Im able to run `smbclient -U user -W SAMBA -L //192.168.0.254` and list all the available shares, but im not able to run this command from another linux computer on the same network. I am able to ssh between these machines, suggesting that there shouldn't be a problem with my networking either.

I used redhat cockpit to create my samba share, and then attempted creating a clean conf manually when that didn't work. Both confs act the same, allowing local connections but not network.

error

```
do_connect: Connection to 192.168.0.254 failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)
```

smb.conf (Modified by Alma and Cockpit)

```
# See smb.conf.example for a more detailed config file or
# read the smb.conf manpage.
# Run 'testparm' to verify the config is correct after
# you modified it.
#
# Note:
# SMB1 is disabled by default. This means clients without support for SMB2 or
# SMB3 are no longer able to connect to smbd (by default).

[global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

        include = registry
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775

[number$]
        comment = Removed
        path = /shares/Number$
        read only = No
```

smb.conf (minimal config)

```
[global]
security = user

[number$]
        writeable = yes
        valid users = USER
        path = /shares/Number$
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, I'm not familiar with firewalld and did not know this was the default on Alma. You can solve this by adding samba to firewalld as outlined [here](https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/open-a-port-or-service.html).

If you prefer using the Cockpit GUI, click on the network tab. Then click on `Edit rules and zones`. From there its incredibly easy to add services.

Comment: This will be the accepted answer when I have the ability to mark it. I have to wait 2 days